# Reference external enum type using EntityObject Generator Template

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, ef-database-first, entityobject

I have the following enum:

```
namespace Common
{
    public enum VehicleType
    {
        Car=10,
        Bike=20
    }
}
```

I have created a reference enum type in EF designer with the name `VehicleType` referencing Common.VehicleType. The edmx is in the `Models` namespace so i end up with two different enums:

```
Common.VehicleType
Models.VehicleType
```

To set the enum on an entity object instance i need to cast it:

```
Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
vehicle.VehicleType = (Models.VehicleType)Common.VehicleType.Bike;
```

There are a couple of problems with this:

1. I need to use fully qualified names (the names of the enums must be the same from what i gather).
2. I need to cast everywhere.
3. I will get a circular reference since the `Models` namespace references `Common` and `Common` now needs to reference `Models` in order to cast.

This is a simplified explanation. I can't change the references or the generator template since that would amount to massive code changes in a quite large project.

I guess its the generation template screwing things up. Is there any way to get around this?

**EDIT**

Fields with type VehicleType generated by EntityObject template generator become:

```
private VehicleType _VehicleType;
```

where VehicleType is Models.VehicleType

Comment: Have you seen this: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/09/11/using-exisiting-enum-types-in-entity-framework-5/? The ultimate problem is that you have 2 enum types and you should not need this.

Comment: I read through it. Am i correct in assuming i have to find a different solution if i am using EntityObject template generator (see updated question)?

Comment: You will have a lot of trouble trying to make it work with EntityObject without hacking. The issue here is that in this case all types must have attributes to be recognized by EF. The enum type generated by the template will have the EdmEnumAttribute and therefore this is the type that will be used by EF and the other type will be ignored. Why you are using EntityObject instead of POCO? If you are ready for hacking you could probably modify the T4 template to not generate the enum type, attribute your type with the EdmEnumTypeAttribute and redirect it to the Enum type from CSDL in the attribut

Comment: Modifying the the T4 template sounds horribly complex. We started this project back when EF 4.0 was the cream of the crop and now the project has grown very large. I have considered moving to DbContext but that would probably take 2 weeks or so - a lot of code to go through. For now i will figure out some workaround until i get the time to move to DbContext. Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: Turns out moving to DbContext was much easier than expected. The two weeks i mentioned was just pulled out of my ass. New territory conquered! \o/

Comment: I am glad that transition to DbContext was smooth.